# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de varias filas seleccionada en un GridView?

Tags: c#, loops, gridview, devexpress

Quisiera saber como recorrer los renglones que han sido seleccioandos en un GridView de DevExpress

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo ese GridView con esos datos y esos 4 renglones seleccionados, lo que quiero es obtener únicamente los datos de los renglones seleccionados para luego mandarlos a un DataTable

La parte de saber si están seleccionados o no, ya la tengo:

```
int renglonesSeleccionados = miGridView.SelectedRowsCount;
if (renglonesSeleccionados == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Tienes que seleccionar por lo menos una fila.");
}
else if (renglonesSeleccionados == 1)
{
    // Aquí hace otra cosa que si funciona pero solo con un renglón
    // ya que lo recorro con un ciclo for para ir obteniendo
    // cada uno de los datos
}
else
{
    // Aquí es donde quiero saber como hacerle para cuando selecciona
    // más de un renglón, poder recorrer cada uno de esos renglones
    // y obtener cada uno de los datos

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Agregar las filas seleccionadas a la lista.
for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.SelectedRowsCount; i++) 
{
   DataRow dtRow = tuDataTable.NewRow();

   if (gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[i] >= 0)
      dtRow.Add(gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[i]));
      tuDataTable.Rows.add(dtRow);
}
```

aca puedes ver mas acerca de como funciona el [GetSelectedRows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetSelectedRowstopic)

aca puedes ver mas acerca de como funciona el [Rows.Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx) para agregar filas a tu datatable

Espero te sea de utilidad

Comment: ¿Y ese arreglo como lo voy agregando a un DataTable?

Comment: recorres el array y por cada rgistro lo guardas en el datatable
´dt.rows.add(rows);´
o tambien puedes ir añadiendo de una vez al datatable en el ´for´ del codigo que te pasé: 
´dt.rows.add(gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[i]));´

Comment: ahi actualice el codigo en la respuesta, intenta y nos comentas si te funciono

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la función **GetSelectedRows()** del Grid View, esa función trae un arreglo de los índices seleccionados, con esto solo es cuestión de recorrer dicho arreglo y extraer la información.

```
DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

tabla.Columns.Add("Clave", typeof(string));  

foreach (int indice in gridView.GetSelectedRows())
{
     DataRow fila = tabla.NewRow();

     fila["Clave"] = gridView.GetRowCellValue(indice, columna).ToString();
     // file["Clave"] = gridView.GetRowCellValue(indice, "ID").ToString(); // Opcion 2

     tabla.Rows.Add(fila);
}
```

a **GetRowCellValue** se le envía el índice de la fila que se quiere leer y hay dos opciones para el segundo parámetro, una es pasarle el **nombre de la variable** que representa la columna que buscar obtener y la otra es poner el nombre que pusiste en la **propiedad FieldName** de la columna que ocupas, ej. "ID".

Adicional, en el ejemplo utilizo **.ToString()** pensando en que el dato es string, si ocupas algún otro, cambia ese cast por el que necesites.